# get elements from an HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my HTML

```
<td class=​"style1 product name" valign=​"top" nowrap>23$​</td>​, 
<td style=​"padding-left:​10px;​" class=​"product name" width=​"85%">productY</td>​
<td class=​"style1 product name" valign=​"top" nowrap>​10$​</td>​, 
<td style=​"padding-left:​10px;​" class=​"product name" width=​"85%">productX</td>​
```

I tried the script below, but this is returning the full html.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("product name")
```

How can i make it work so that it would return productX and productY in an array?

please let me know
thanks

Comment: Consider looping through the array that `.getElementsByClassName` returns and using a conditional to push only elements you want to a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes cannot contain spaces, so `class=​"product name"` is actually two classes:  **product** and **name**.

Given your current HTML, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.product.name:not(.style1)')` to grab the elements with classes **product** and **name**, while excluding those having class **style1**.

You can iterate through this list, grabbing the text content of each element like so:

```js
var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product.name:not(.style1)'),
    a = [],
    i;

for(i = 0 ; i < products.length ; i++) {
  a.push(products[i].textContent);
}

console.log(a);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="style1 product name" valign="top" nowrap>23$</td>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;" class="product name" width="85%">productY</td>
    <td class="style1 product name" valign="top" nowrap>10$</td>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;" class="product name" width="85%">productX</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, but i am getting undefined. However when i use this        document.querySelectorAll('.product name:not(.style1)')[0].textContent; 
It is giving me the product 0 name. How can i add this in the loop to get the other products name?

Comment: Do you see `undefined` when you run the Snippet?

Comment: thanks for your help - this one worked - var x = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".product.name:not(.style1)"));

Answer (score 1):

please try this one

```js
var x = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".product.name:not(.style1)"));

console.log(x);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="style1 product name" valign="top" nowrap>23$</td>,
    <td style="padding-left:10px;" class="product name" width="85%">productY</td>
    <td class="style1 product name" valign="top" nowrap>10$</td>,
    <td style="padding-left:10px;" class="product name" width="85%">productX</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: previously i use iteration using `Array.protoype.filter.call(x,function(elm){...})`, thanks to @RickHitchCock for his simplest syntax `:not(.style1)`

Answer (score 0):

`var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("product name")` creates and array of elements with class name `product name`. Then you can acces this array like this `elements[0]...etc.`

Product name must be one word `product-name` because now your `td` has 3 classes

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have 2 classes applied to elements with `class="product name"`. The first class is `product` and the second class is `name`. In HTML, multiple CSS classes are separated by spaces. Instead, try to use `"product_name"` (with an underscore).

### HTML:

```
<td class=​"style1 product name" valign=​"top" nowrap>23$​</td>​, 
<td style=​"padding-left:​10px;​" class=​"product_name" width=​"85%">productY</td>​
<td class=​"style1 product name" valign=​"top" nowrap>​10$​</td>​, 
<td style=​"padding-left:​10px;​" class=​"product_name" width=​"85%">productX</td>​
```

### Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("product_name")
```

Comment: Then use `document.getElementsByClassName("product")` and then of that group, check if each one also has a class of `"name"` as well. As written, it's 2 separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like `product-item` as classname to your product elements:

```
var products = document.getElementsByClassName("product-items");
for (var i = 0; i<products.length; i++) {
    console.log(products[i].innerText);
}
```